# ggplot_colour palette error. Insufficient values in manual scale. 6 needed but only 3 provided

Tags: r, ggplot2, palette

Unable to get plots to print - asking for Error in `palette()`:
! Insufficient values in manual scale. 6 needed but only 3 provided.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Code that i’m running

```r
Data = read.csv("S1_tp plots_BSF.csv")
require(Rmisc)
require(ggplot2)
require(grid)
theme_bw()
library(gridExtra)
require(gridExtra)
library(devtools)
require(devtools)
devtools::install_github("wilkelab/cowplot", force=TRUE)

require(cowplot)
# replacing "tp' with tp
#replacing 'Treatment' with stage.


Datase <- summarySE(Data,na.rm=TRUE, measurevar="tp", groupvars=c("Location","stage","time"))

## Not in this code ## Datase$Site <- factor(Datase$Site, levels=c("1","2","3"))
Datase$stage <- factor(Datase$stage)
## Datase$Treatment <- factor(Datase$Treatment, levels=c("Zero","Five","Ten","Fifteen","Twenty","Ramp"))
Datase$Location<-factor(Datase$Location, labels=c("B0","B5","B10","B15","B20","BR"))
Datase$time<-factor(Datase$time,c("0", "1","2", "3","4", "5","6", "7","8", "10","14"))

B0 = ggplot(Datase[Datase$Location=="B0",], aes(x=time, y=tp,group=(stage),shape = factor(stage))) + scale_shape_manual(name = "",values=c(16,6,5))+ 
  theme_bw()+xlab("")+ylab(expression(paste("Individuals", " ", m^-2,"", sep="")))+theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())+
  geom_line(position=position_dodge(0),size = 0.5)+ theme(text = element_text(size=20))+facet_grid(.~Location, scales="free_y")+ theme(strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text = element_blank()) +geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge(0),aes(ymin=tp-se,ymax=tp+se),width=.1,colour="stage") +
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(0),size = 5)+ theme(text = element_text(size=20))+guides(shape = guide_legend(reverse=F))+ theme(legend.position="none",legend.key.size = unit(0.1, "cm"))+facet_grid(.~Location, scales="free_y")  +geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge(0),aes(ymin=tp-se,ymax=tp+se),width=.1,colour="black") +
  facet_wrap(~Location) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,100))

B5 = ggplot(Datase[Datase$Location=="B5",], aes(x=time, y=tp,group=(stage),shape = factor(stage))) + scale_shape_manual(name = "",values=c(16,6,5))+ 
  theme_bw()+xlab("")+ylab(expression(paste(" ")))+theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())+
  geom_line(position=position_dodge(0),size = 0.5)+ theme(text = element_text(size=20))+facet_grid(.~Location, scales="free_y")+ theme(strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text = element_blank()) +geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge(0),aes(ymin=tp-se,ymax=tp+se),width=.1,colour="black") +
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(0),size = 5)+ theme(text = element_text(size=20))+guides(shape = guide_legend(reverse=F))+ theme(legend.position="none",legend.key.size = unit(0.1, "cm"))+facet_grid(.~Location, scales="free_y")  +geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge(0),aes(ymin=tp-se,ymax=tp+se),width=.1,colour="black") +
  facet_wrap(~Location) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,100))

B10 = ggplot(Datase[Datase$Location=="B10",], aes(x=time, y=tp,group=(stage),shape = factor(stage))) + scale_shape_manual(name = "",values=c(16,6,5))+ 
  theme_bw()+xlab("")+ylab(expression(paste(" ")))+theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())+
  geom_line(position=position_dodge(0),size = 0.5)+ theme(text = element_text(size=20))+facet_grid(.~Location, scales="free_y")+ theme(strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text = element_blank()) +geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge(0),aes(ymin=tp-se,ymax=tp+se),width=.1,colour="black") +
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(0),size = 5)+ theme(text = element_text(size=20))+guides(shape = guide_legend(reverse=F))+ theme(legend.position="none",legend.key.size = unit(0.1, "cm"))+facet_grid(.~Location, scales="free_y")  +geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge(0),aes(ymin=tp-se,ymax=tp+se),width=.1,colour="black") +
  facet_wrap(~Location) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,100))

B15 = ggplot(Datase[Datase$Location=="B15",], aes(x=time, y=tp,group=(stage),shape = factor(stage))) + scale_shape_manual(name = "",values=c(16,6,5))+ 
  theme_bw()+xlab("")+ylab(expression(paste(" ")))+theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())+
  geom_line(position=position_dodge(0),size = 0.5)+ theme(text = element_text(size=20))+facet_grid(.~Location, scales="free_y")+ theme(strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text = element_blank()) +geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge(0),aes(ymin=tp-se,ymax=tp+se),width=.1,colour="black") +
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(0),size = 5)+ theme(text = element_text(size=20))+guides(shape = guide_legend(reverse=F))+ theme(legend.position="none",legend.key.size = unit(0.1, "cm"))+facet_grid(.~Location, scales="free_y")  +geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge(0),aes(ymin=tp-se,ymax=tp+se),width=.1,colour="black") +
  facet_wrap(~Location) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,100))


B15 <- B15 + guides(shape=guide_legend(override.aes=list(size=6)))
A <-gridExtra::grid.arrange(B0,B5,B10,B15, ncol=3)
```

I have tried the following final output....

```r
A <-gridExtra::grid.arrange(B0,B5,B10,B15,ncol=3)
```

and was expecting four plots to be printed 3 x 2.

The following message was returned.

```
> A <-gridExtra::grid.arrange(B0,B5,B10,B15, ncol=3)  
Error in `palette()`:
! Insufficient values in manual scale. 6 needed but only 3 provided.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Some help getting these survival plots printed would be very much appreciated. Needed for seminar at the end of the week and final thesis.  Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like your data has six `stage` values that you are mapping to shape, but you only specify 3 shapes. Is that possible? Does the error go away if you remove the `scale_shape_manual(name = "",values=c(16,6,5))` lines?

Comment: Jon Spring. Thank you so much for such a quick response. Yes that has worked!  Thank you.